# How to import data from mongodb to apache solr using mongo-connector

Tags: mongodb, apache, solr, connector

I am new to apache solr. I want to import data from mongodb to solr using mongo-connector for my search application. I followed steps from https://github.com/mongodb-labs/mongo-connector/wiki/Getting-Started.

I created replicaSet and replicaSet is running fine.
I have also installed mongo-connector using pip install but when issue the following command:

> mongo-connector -m localhost:27017 -t http://localhost:8983/solr -d solr_doc_manager

its not working. It is stuck at

> Logging to mongo-connector.log.

This is the only line I am getting. How can I get rid of this problem?

Comment: I get the same problem too

Comment: have you found a solution to this problem please?

Comment: Please mention the Solr and Mongo version that you are using.

Comment: I am also having the same problem. Did you find any solution ?

Comment: did you try adding new adding new records to mongo collection and check??

Comment: can you re-run this with -vvvvv (big verbosity)

Answer (score 0):

The Logging to mongo-connector.log. is not the error ,
it indicates that the mongo connector is started logging to mongo-connector.log
if you insert the data to mongodb , it starts pushing to solr