# Linking Solr to MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, solr

I'm trying to link Solr to MongoDB in order to make search queries,
I read about mongo-connector : https://github.com/mongodb-labs/mongo-connector , I followed the steps there :I downloaded mongo-connector(using pip install), I have a Solr core, added LukeRequestHandler to solrConfig.xml, modified schema.xml to be the same as the schema.xml in the example of mongo-connector and ran a replicaSet in mongodb . So everything seemed right to me, but when I ran `mongo-connector -m localhost:27017 -t http://localhost:27017 -t http://localhost:8983/solr/#/mycore -d solr_doc_manager` in the mongo shell nothing happens and it gives me the sign that the sentence is incomplete. How can I fix that ?

Comment: Are you sure you're supposed to run it in the mongo shell and not a regular shell? mongo-connector connects to mongod as a replication node and reads / receives the oplog, and is not a command inside mongo as far as I understand.

Comment: @MatsLindh when I run it in a regular shell he says that the command is not recognized

Comment: @MatsLindh I'm using windows so I tried executing it in windows terminal and on Cygwin

Comment: @MatsLindh the command threw this error : ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded , any idea why please?

Comment: No idea, but it sounds like it's not getting the data it's looking for (either because it gets an error message, or because it just doesn't get anything). If it uses JSON as it's config format, that can be an issue as well (as I can see that it has a config.json on github). You could add debug statements to the code, but that would require you to know a bit of python.

Comment: @MatsLindh thanks, it turned out to be a problem with luke handler, so now my problem is like this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37894301/how-to-import-data-from-mongodb-to-apache-solr-using-mongo-connector